# How can I overlay an image in a fluid layout (zurb foundation)

Tags: css, wordpress, overflow, zurb-foundation

I am trying to position an image inside a wordpress menu bar so that it is shown at the home-buttons position but overlaying all other content (see images)
The theme is based on Zurb's Foundation framework

What I got:
[image]

How it is supposed to be:
[image]

(The home-button will be smaller horizontaly in the end)

I already tried overflow:visible and then repositioning the image with margins, it did not work unfortunately, because the image still gets clipped.

You can see the code in action, with source on this page: [removed]. I think its easier this way, so you can see all the css in action.

Thank you very much for all answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this result, using in the image

```
position: relative;
z-index: 99;
```

Comment: It works. I knew it had to be something easy, but I just couldn't wrap my head around it. Thanks a ton!

Comment: No problem! that's why I'm here.